# Open a PNG in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, png, jupyter

Im trying this code to open an image in a jupyter notebook with python.

This is the code:

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# Read Images 
img = mpimg.imread('C:/Users/alvar/Desktop/IE/1 - Full-time/Term 2/Machine Learning 2/Assigments/Group/For sunday/Tanzania.png') 

# Output Images 
plt.imshow(img)
```

And is giving me this error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         3 
>         4 # Read Images
>   ----> 5 img = mpimg.imread('C:/Users/alvar/Desktop/IE/1 - Full-time/Term 2/Machine Learning 2/Assigments/Group/For
>   sunday/Tanzania.png')
>         6 
>         7 # Output Images
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in imread(fname,
>   format)    1373         else:    1374             with open(fname,
>   'rb') as fd:
>   -> 1375                 return handler(fd)    1376     else:    1377         return handler(fname)
>
> ValueError: invalid PNG header

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib: ValueError: invalid PNG header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39379609/matplotlib-valueerror-invalid-png-header)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just inserting a png just for reference in a Jupyter notebook you could consider taking advantage of a [markdown](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html) cell and using the following code:

```
<img src=“path_to_image/image.png”>
```